# Average across lists of lists in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a loop where I get list of lists:

```
for i in range(num_exp):
  li = func()
```

where `li` is list of lists of the form 
`[["s1", 1, 2], ["s2", 2, 3], ["s3", 3, 4]]` 
(first item is string and rest 2 items are numerics)

I want to average numeric values across each `li` in a loop.
So for `num_exp = 3` and li's

```
[["s1", 1, 2], ["s2", 3, 4], ["s3", 5, 6]]
[["s1", 2, 3], ["s2", 4, 5], ["s3", 6, 7]]
[["s1", 3, 4], ["s2", 5, 6], ["s3", 7, 8]]
```

I would get

```
[["s1", 6/3, 9/3], ["s2", 12/3, 15/3], ["s3", 18/3, 21/3]]
```

I want to do it in numpy. In simply python I do as follows

```
 dic = {}
 for l in li:
     if l[0] not in dic:
        dic[l[0]] = l[1:]
      else:
        dic[l[0]][0] += l[1] 
        dic[l[0]][1] += l[2] 

 fl = []
 for m in dic:
    fl.append([m, dic[m][0]/num_exp, dic[m[1]/num_exp])
```

but it seems rather inefficient

Comment: Since you are starting with lists (of lists), your pure Python solution might well be the fastest.  Making numpy arrays is not a cost-less operation.

Comment: @hpaulj I see, well, I guess it might be. Numpy also usually offers very concise well-readable and understandable code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `np.array` from list of lists `li` specifying `dtype='object'` and `swapaxes` to group same `s` into same group. Slicing 2 last elements on axis 2 (right-most axis), and `sum`, and divide it by `num_exp`. Finally, `column_stack` unique string values to it.

```
num_exp = 3
li = [[["s1", 1, 2], ["s2", 3, 4], ["s3", 5, 6]],
      [["s1", 2, 3], ["s2", 4, 5], ["s3", 6, 7]],
      [["s1", 3, 4], ["s2", 5, 6], ["s3", 7, 8]]]

arr = np.array(li, dtype='object').swapaxes(0, 1)

Out[372]:
array([[['s1', 1, 2],
        ['s1', 2, 3],
        ['s1', 3, 4]],

       [['s2', 3, 4],
        ['s2', 4, 5],
        ['s2', 5, 6]],

       [['s3', 5, 6],
        ['s3', 6, 7],
        ['s3', 7, 8]]], dtype=object)

arr1 = arr[...,[1,2]].sum(axis=1) / num_exp

Out[380]:
array([[2.0, 3.0],
       [4.0, 5.0],
       [6.0, 7.0]], dtype=object)

s = arr[:,0, 0]
result = np.column_stack([s, arr1])

Out[389]:
array([['s1', 2.0, 3.0],
       ['s2', 4.0, 5.0],
       ['s3', 6.0, 7.0]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a speed comparison of a pure python solution with a numpy one.

```
In [167]: alist                                                                                              
Out[167]: 
[[['s1', 1, 2], ['s2', 3, 4], ['s3', 5, 6]],
 [['s1', 2, 3], ['s2', 4, 5], ['s3', 6, 7]],
 [['s1', 3, 4], ['s2', 5, 6], ['s3', 7, 8]]]
```

With a defaultdict from collections:

```
In [169]: def foo1(alist): 
     ...:     dd = defaultdict(list) 
     ...:     for row in alist: 
     ...:         for col in row: 
     ...:             dd[col[0]].append(col[1:]) 
     ...:     return [[k, np.mean(v,0)] for k,v in dd.items()] 
     ...:                                                                                                    
In [170]: foo1(alist)                                                                                        
Out[170]: [['s1', array([2., 3.])], ['s2', array([4., 5.])], ['s3', array([6., 7.])]]
```

This list isn't perfect, but close enough for testing purposes.  Also not quite pure Python since I'm using `np.mean` for each key.

A numpy solution using a 3d object dtype array (to preserve strings):

```
In [171]: def foo2(alist): 
     ...:     arr = np.array(alist, object) 
     ...:     lbl = arr[0,:,0][:,None]  
     ...:     res = arr[:,:,1:].mean(axis=0) 
     ...:     return np.concatenate((lbl,res),axis=1) 
     ...:                                                                                                    
In [172]: foo2(alist)                                                                                        
Out[172]: 
array([['s1', 2.0, 3.0],
       ['s2', 4.0, 5.0],
       ['s3', 6.0, 7.0]], dtype=object)
```

Some timings:

```
In [173]: timeit foo1(alist)                                                                                 
98.2 µs ± 256 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [174]: timeit foo2(alist)                                                                                 
42.1 µs ± 1.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

and for a big list:

```
In [175]: blist=alist*10000                                                                                  
In [176]: timeit foo1(blist)                                                                                 
71.9 ms ± 350 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [177]: timeit foo2(blist)                                                                                 
46.8 ms ± 489 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So roughly a 2x speed advantage for numpy.  Nice, but not a make-or-break advantage.

===

I reworked the defaultdict function to use its own `mean` function:

```
In [188]: def foo11(alist): 
     ...:     nexp = len(alist) 
     ...:     def mean(v): 
     ...:        return [sum(i)/nexp for i in zip(*v)] 
     ...:     dd = defaultdict(list) 
     ...:     for row in alist: 
     ...:         for col in row: 
     ...:             dd[col[0]].append(col[1:]) 
     ...:     return [[k, *mean(v)] for k,v in dd.items()] 
     ...:      
     ...:                                                                                                    
In [189]: foo11(alist)                                                                                       
Out[189]: [['s1', 2.0, 3.0], ['s2', 4.0, 5.0], ['s3', 6.0, 7.0]]

In [190]: timeit foo11(alist)                                                                                
9.43 µs ± 13 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [191]: timeit foo11(blist)                                                                                
51.9 ms ± 206 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

This is much faster for the small example, and about the same speed as `foo2` for the large one.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are a nuisance when you're trying to do calculations, so strip them off, do the calculations, and put them back.

```py
data = []
for i in range(num_exp):
    li = func()
    # Goodbye strings
    data.append([elm[1:] for elm in li])

averages = np.mean(data, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do everything in one line with numpy

```
[np.concatenate((li[0][x][0:1], li[:,x][:,1:].astype('float').mean(axis=0).astype('S1'))) for x in np.arange(0,num_exp)]
```

But, you may find Pandas `DataFrame`s to provide a more practical API for working with mixed data-type arrays.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,3,4,5,6,7],[3,4,5,6,7,8]],columns=['s1','s1','s2','s2','s3','s3']).mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the function `func()` and `num_exp = 3`, first you should execute `func` as many times a you need in the for loop and add the results based on the string key. Since we already know how many times we are going to execute `func`, we can divide the return values by this number. I expect `li` to have exactly your structure of a key and numbers afterwards.

```
result_dict = dict()
for i in range(num_exp):
    li = func(i)

    for l in li:
        sums = result_dict.get(l[0], np.zeros(len(l) - 1))
        result_dict[l[0]] = (l[1:] / num_exp) + sums
```

The `result_dict` would look like this: `{'s1': [2.0, 3.0], 's2': [4.0, 5.0], 's3': [6.0, 7.0]}`

Now we just need to transform the dictionary into your desired structure and we're done.

```
result = [[key, *arr] for (key, arr) in result_dict.items()]
```

This creates `result` as `[['s1', 2.0, 3.0], ['s2', 4.0, 5.0], ['s3', 6.0, 7.0]]`

Comment: @YohanRoth Now it should work for numpy. Credit to Maxwell

Comment: what do you mean? you aren't using any numpy functions still

Comment: @YohanRoth First of all `np.zeros` is a numpy function. Second you dont have to explicitly use numpy function for python to "use numpy functions", e.g. `(l[1:] / num_exp) + sums` actually uses two numpy functions that do not work with normal lists. And third, do you want an numpy array as a result or what explicitly is the problem with this solution

Comment: If you are starting with lists, the cost of creating an array can cancel the calculation advantages.  Sometimes pure list solutions are faster.